# IE9 doesn't like naked numbers in CSS?

Tags: html, css, styles

This works in Chrome, Safari and Firefox, but not in IE9

```
style='height:100'
```

IE9 just ignores it. But this DOES work:

```
style='height:100px'
```

Unfortunately, i really truly do not want to have to go around adding a "px" to all my values. It makes doing any sort of manipulation (for example, multiplying the width by two, adding 100 to it, etc.) incredibly troublesome. Is this expected behaviour, and is there any special flag somewhere i can set to get IE9 to accept the first example?

(i know inline styles are generally considered incredibly bad, but i have reason to use them anyway in some special cases)

Comment: You might have intended to have `100%`, in which case all those browsers will have got it wrong. CSS does require you to be specific with your units.

Comment: When you say it makes "any sort of manipulation incredibly troublesome", are you talking about JavaScript, or?

Comment: "any sort" means anything. Javascript, Python, etc.. The examples i gave prettymuch summed it up. Rather than x = x * 2 i now have x = (parseInt(x) * 2) + "px", which is just about twice as many characters, with plenty of lovely cruft obscuring the purpose of the operation, and is just all around nasty. Python would be similar, unless I am completely missing something? In fact, i do not see any way at all any sort of manipulation will not be incredibly troublesome, regardless of language, whether the manipulation is simple or complex, whether i am doing it seldom or often.

Comment: Well, you either put up with the cruft, or write functions to abstract it away. For example, using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) you can do `var x = $('#myDiv').width(); x = x * 2; $('#myDiv').width(x);`.

Comment: In addition to what thirtydot said, you could use the jQuery sizes plugin to help you with that ( http://www.bramstein.com/projects/jsizes/ )

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`style='height:100'` may work in some tolerant browsers, but is actually invalid CSS, so IE has every right to refuse to parse those.

Comment: It's not about how "tolerant" the browser is - no(?) browser will allow this in "Standards Mode". Most (all?) browsers have a "Quirks Mode" that will allow things like this to slip by, here's some documentation on this for Firefox: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/mozilla_quirks_mode_behavior

Comment: You are right, but in the original question, it looks like Chrome, Safari and Firefox are in Quirks mode, and I'm guessing IE9 should be, too. Different browsers may tolerate different errors in Quirks mode, that's what I meant by "tolerant".

Answer (score 3):

That (`width:100`) doesn't actually work in any of those browsers due to being invalid CSS:

http://jsbin.com/ovewus

```
<div style="width:100;background:red">test</div>
```

**..unless your page is in [Quirks Mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode)** due to not having a valid doctype, like this:

http://jsbin.com/ovewus/2 - `width:100`
 works!

Intentionally writing pages for Quirks Mode is doubly incredibly bad, just don't do it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see "naked" numbers here :) http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#the-width-property as 100 can be px,em..

" Specifies the width of the content area **using a length unit**."

Answer (score 0):

As Gruikya said, it is invalid CSS to have non-unit numbers (unless the number is 0, or the style is `line-height`), so I would definitely recommend adding the correct units. If you need to do mathematical operations on those units, (I presume in Javascript) then you should be using `parseInt` or `parseFloat` anyway, and these will happily ignore the trailing units.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't define any size without actually defining the unit. You're making browsers guess what unit you want to use, because you're not telling them.

Depending on what CSS standard is followed by the browser, different browsers may handle it  differently.

The CSS2 specification defines rules without units should be ignored. It also mention this behavior may (theoretically) change in [future specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#parsing-errors).